# What did 3rd Party Accessories sell for on Black Friday last year (2011) at the Apple Store?

Tags: accessories, apple-store

Not sure if this was the appropriate place to ask, but it is Apple related so here we go:

This is Apple's 2nd year of doing Black Friday sales, does anyone have any information on what 3rd party accessories were discounted by last year during the sales? I have a few things I'd like to get, but if the discount isn't too great or non-existant it might not be worth fighting the crowds for.

I'm aware that the iPhones / Macs were discounted for < $100.

Answer (score 2):

Go now and buy what you want would be my advice. If it subsequently goes on sale, go and ask for a price adjustment on Friday. *(Don't wait till Saturday to ask, though)*

Apple's return policy is quite consumer friendly, so you could always not open things if you are on the fence and exchange or even return it until after the New Year due to the extended holiday season return policy.

Even if I had a list of things on sale - each store has different stock, different models so guessing which items will be in stock at your store will be hit or miss.

Also - [Apple's announcement](http://store.apple.com/us/browse/holiday/shopping_event) states that you can start shopping online at Midnight, so you can make your go/no-go decision well before the stores open on Friday. I would get the [Apple Store app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-store/id375380948?mt=8) installed on your iOS device so you can shop, pay and not wait in line for items that they don't have stashed at the "rapid sales" line where many popular items are stocked in large quantities to minimize the delay of getting your item from the stockroom or finding someone free to sell you your new loot.

Comment: I don't mean to question your authority or answer here @bmike, but it seems that this type of question is not appropriate for the site. The [FAQ](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) page notes as much in fairly certain terms (Please **refrain from asking** about ...i.e., "a shopping or buying recommendation for hardware or accessories like bags and cases"). My feeling is that providing answers to questions like these encourages more like them, thereby diminishing the purpose and stated goals of the site.